# Keeping Table Relationships when Exporting from SSMS to MS Access

Tags: ms-access, export, ssms

I am currently managing two databases for a customer. The contract is ending soon and they are requesting that we export their data to Access before handing it over.

I noticed that Access does not keep the table relationships. There doesn't seem to be an option in the SSMS Export Wizard. There also seems to be a solution when sending data TO SSMS but not the other way around. Is there another workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a means to do the reverse.

However, what you can do is create a blank Access database. Link one table to sql server.

Then execute a transferDatabase command (it operates on one table).

the result of the above is that you now have all tables in Access. You WOULD have to re-create the relationships, but all PK and FK keys would be un-changed, and thus you can setup and re-create the relationships in Access. If you have say 25 tables? Then create a new table in that database (say my tables) and from SSMS execute a query to send all current tables in the database to that "table". (remove the MyTable - and perhaps any others you don't want to transfer).

Now, from the Access side, link to that MyTables, and process the rows for each table - executing a transfer Database command for each given table in that MyTale list. So at that point you have all data and tables in Access. As noted, you will have to re-create the relationships.

Another way? Just create a blank Access database. use the linked table wizard or the import wizard - you can import all tables in one shot. - you thus not need the above code. This is certainly the least amount of work. You can use the external data tab, and choose to create "links" or in fact local tables. So you can well with ease import all tables + data. But setting up and creating of the relationships will have to be done by manually (by hand).